# Error - Heap block at 00352D10 modified at 00352D1C past requested size of 4

Tags: c

This my code:

```
struct etf_t{
    int id;
    char* name;
    List CompanyList;
    Map CompanyPercentage;
};

Etf EtfCreate(int id, char* name)
{
    if(name==NULL) return NULL;
    Etf etf=malloc(sizeof(*etf));
    if(etf==NULL) return NULL;
    etf->id=id;
    etf->name=malloc(sizeof(strlen(name)+1));
    if(etf->name==NULL) return NULL;
    strcpy(etf->name,name);
    etf->CompanyList=NULL;
    etf->CompanyPercentage=NULL;
    return etf;
}

void EtfFree (Etf etf)
{
    if(!etf) return;
    if(etf->name!=NULL) free(etf->name);
    mapDestroy(etf->CompanyPercentage);
    listDestroy(etf->CompanyList);
    free(etf);
}
```

or at least some of it, now while using the following simple code to test it:

```
bool testetfcreate()
{
    Etf fail= EtfCreate(1, NULL);
    ASSERT_TEST(fail==NULL);
    Etf new = EtfCreate(1,"first");
    ASSERT_TEST(new!=NULL);
    EtfFree(new);
    return true;
}
```

I get the given error in line `free(etf->name)`; {in the `EtfFree` function.}

Error - Heap block at `00352D10` modified at `00352D1C` past requested size of 4

Now I know usually the source for this error is if I tried to write to a memory I haven't allocated, but I don't see it happening here since i allocate `strlen+1`
I should have all the space for the name string and the `'\0'` char at the end.

So why is this happening?

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: You have not posted enough code to reproduce the problem, so any answer you get can only be speculation. Please isolate the problem in a minimum working example.

Comment: what does `mapDestroy` and `listDestroy` do? `Etf EtfCreate(int id, char* name)` should be `Etf EtfCreate(int id, const char* name)` if you want to call it like you did.

Comment: the map destroy and list destroy are functions that delete map and list data. but in this particular situation they're not used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the error is the `malloc(sizeof(strlen(name)+1))` expression. The sizeof operator evaluates to the size of the type of its operand. The type of `strlen(name) + 1` is `int` and its size is 4. So you allocate 4 bytes of memory regardless of the length of string `name`. Remove the sizeof operator and your code should work.